# How to disable Command + Left keyboard shortcut in Yosemite

Tags: macos, keyboard, mission-control

CMD + LEFT is a really important shortcut that i use in multiple applications on my mac: (go to back in google chrome, to put the cursor in the beginning of line in any IDE...etc.). however, it seems that in Yosemite(?) this command seems to move my window left.

how do i disable this keyboard shortcut? (same with CMD+RIGHT)

i looked in mission control and system settings keyboard, but couldn't find anything

Comment: Check your shortcuts under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. I just tested and Cmd+→ and Cmd+← seem to be working as intended in Yosemite (meaning left arrow makes it go back in Chrome, etc).

Comment: @tubedogg i'm guessing i must have something installed that is interfering? is there a way to check this? I double checked my sys prefs > keyboard > shortcuts and there is nothing on CMD + ←

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. i found out why - apparently someone installed BetterSnapTool on the server, which does this.